# SVN server error: Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response. [500, #0]

Tags: svn

We run a Linux SVN server (Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 SVN/1.7.6 mod_ssl/2.2.22 and OpenSSL/0.9.8x) and we sometimes get the following errors in the error log files.

The clients use a JAVA application that synchronises data from the repository via HTTPS. The client application uses the following components:

- svnclientadapter-1.8.0.jar
- svnjavahl-1.7.4.jar

Log file shows:

```
[Thu Apr 24 21:03:39 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[Thu Apr 24 21:03:39 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #103]
[Thu Apr 24 21:03:39 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] Error writing base64 data: Software caused connection abort  [500, #103]
[Thu Apr 24 21:28:33 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[Thu Apr 24 21:28:33 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #103]
[Thu Apr 24 21:28:33 2014] [error] [client 70.198.65.85] Error writing base64 data: Software caused connection abort  [500, #103]
```

Does someone have any idea ? Thank you in advance

Comment: In my case, the issue was a string-replace filter I had on an intermediate reverse proxy server. I removed the string-replace filter and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install apache2-mpm-prefork on svn server, if you don't have it yet, in ubuntu it can be done with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
```

We had similar problem, in our case this problem appeared when we had more than one client at a time.

Comment: When you suggest a solution to a problem, could you please explain what this is all about (i.e., what is apache2-mpm-prefork?) and why this might work?